# Initialization of Json Array values to existing ajax function on document ready

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have an working ajax function passing values from an array. The thing is, as i will have loads of translations, i want to create a json file with all the translations and then turn it accessible to my main ajax function. The thing is, my values are not loading on document ready, just when i change the language.

My function i18n it´s not loading o document ready and it gives me an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'en' of undefined". I tried to execute my updateForecast function inside of i18n one, it loads the values on document ready but then i´m in loop.

What i´m doing wrong? For a quick reference, you can see the working example here - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23044665/test/index.html

```
 $(function(){


        //
        // Translations
        //
        var trans;
        function i18n (key, value) {

                    $.getJSON("translations.json", function(json){
               trans = json[0];
            });

            if ( trans != 'undefined' && trans[language] != 'undefined' && trans[language][key] != 'undefined') {
                return  trans[language][key]
            }

            return value;
        }




            function updateForecast() {

            var forecast = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?id=" + city_id + "&units=" + units + "&cnt="+ (parseInt(forecast_days)+1) +"&lang=en";

            // Define Ajax Call
            $.ajax({
                url: forecast,
                async: true,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {

                     // Execute Translation function
                i18n();

                    var firstItem = data.list[0]; 
                    var secondItem = data.list[0].weather[0]; 

                alert(trans[language].weather[secondItem.id]);


               },
               error: function( data ) {
                 alert( "ERROR:");
               }
            });

        }

        updateForecast(); // for init update!

    });
```

Comment: you really need to do a far better job of explaining with more precision and some code what your issue is

Comment: You´re right, sorry!! I´ve updated my post with a more detailed explanation of my problem!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved the problem. Instead of using this getJSON inside of my i18n function

```
    $.getJSON(url, function(json){
       trans = json[0];
    });
```

I used an ajax call like this one with the parameter async:false.

```
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            trans = json[0];
        }
    });
```

And voilá, my json data was loaded on document ready and treated by my main function updateForecast.

And again thanks a lot to who tried to help me.

Answer (score -1):

collect all the data in JS Array(needs well categorized data ), then use  'JSON.Stringify' to get data in JSON format ., now you can pass the data through the AJAX call/post

Comment: if you want to load data dynamically just go ahead and try with jquery as follows: $(document).on('someSelector', 'someEvent', 'someData');

Comment: I want to make all data accessible. If you click on my link, on document ready, you´ll see a console error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'en' of undefined.". Then, if you select language on select box all my data loads as expected, and no console error anymore! Why? By the way thanks for your comment!

Comment: i don't get why someone gave a -ve flag on my answer... my answer was just an idea to use JSON.Stringify

Comment: Wasn´t me! By the way, your comment was really construtive you shown me something that i never heard!! :)

Comment: @Legues ... i didn't mean its you... don't be offended.. and i am using it in my project... i know you might not heard about it but i figured it out as i work closely with JS and knockoutJS